# Clickable Components within Parallax Layer with React-Spring not working?

Tags: navbar, parallax, react-spring

I am trying to build a nav bar into one of my Parallax Layers in react using React Spring. The nav bar buttons are not clickable, and I am confused as to why. I have been searching around for a while, but am not able to find documentation on how to get components to function within Parallax Layers. Thanks!

my nav bar component
`

```
function NavBar() {

    const clicked = () => {
        return(
            console.log('clicky clacky')
        )
    }

    return (
        <div>

            <nav className="layer">
                <button onClick={clicked} className="button">Daily Facts</button>
                <button onClick={clicked} className="button">Alien Town</button><button onClick={clicked} className="button">Another Dimension</button>
            </nav> 
        </div>
    );                       
}

export default NavBar;
```

my app component with all the parallax layers, the nav bar component is placed all the way at the bottom

```
import { Parallax, ParallaxLayer } from "@react-spring/parallax";
import moon from "./pixil-layer-Moon.png"
import stars1 from "./pixil-layer-2.png"
import stars2 from "./pixil-layer-3.png"
import ufo from "./pixil-layer-4.png"
import planet from "./planet.png"
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import NavBar from "./NavBar";


function Homepage() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Parallax pages={4}>

                <ParallaxLayer
                    offset={0}
                    factor={4}
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(${moon})`,
                        backgroundSize: 'cover'
                    }}
                >
                </ParallaxLayer>

                <ParallaxLayer
                    offset={0}
                    factor={4}
                    speed={.5}
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(${planet})`,
                        backgroundSize: 'cover',
                    }}
                >
                </ParallaxLayer>

                <ParallaxLayer
                    offset={0}
                    speed={.5}
                    factor={3}
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(${stars1})`,
                        backgroundSize: 'cover'
                    }}
                >
                </ParallaxLayer>

                <ParallaxLayer
                    offset={0}
                    speed={2}
                    factor={4}
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url(${stars2})`,
                        backgroundSize: 'cover'
                    }}
                >
                </ParallaxLayer>

                <ParallaxLayer
                    sticky={{ start: 0, end: 3 }}
                >
                    <img style={{ width: '1500px', height: 'auto' }} src={ufo} />
                </ParallaxLayer>

                <ParallaxLayer
                    offset={3}
                    speed={.5}
                >
                    <div className="text">
                        <h1>Space Is The Place!</h1>
                    </div>
                    <NavBar />
                </ParallaxLayer>
            </Parallax>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Homepage`
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. What happened in my case was that the parallax layer had a higher z-index, which placed it over the button. This made the button unclickable. Using inspect elements and adding a console.log in your onclick() method might help in debugging. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the pointerEvents css property to disable the pointer on the others layers.